# Setting up Dokku with MySQL and Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean, dokku

Right off the bat, this is the issue:

```
$ dokku mysql:create app
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/git’: Permission denied
```

Dumb founded... Here's what I did:

I went to Digital Ocean and got a Dokku server. From there I set it up by simply going to the IP and pushing the blue button.

I then [followed this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-digitalocean-image-to-run-a-ruby-on-rails-app) except that I made a deviation with the [dokku mysql plugin](https://github.com/hughfletcher/dokku-mysql-plugin).

Let me know if you need anymore information. Will happily update my question per a comment.

**Key Question**: How do I set up a MySQL DB given that I am having the above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an answer here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-install-mysql-on-dokku

Short: use this fork https://github.com/k2nr/dokku-mysql-plugin